# How can I implement Single Sign On for MVC and WebApi With IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

Currently I am working in a Solution with next projects:

1. IdentityServer
2. Web Application
3. WebApi Aplication

Until now Identity Server its authenticating Web Application pretty well, however, once a user has been successfully authenticated on (2) I need this user could authenticated on (3) with the same credentials. Since I am calling Services from (3) with JavaScript (from browser).

I tried to to with oidc-client and manually by setting "Authorization" Bearer token without any success.

So you have any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: to implement SSO, you need to use cookie authentication and save the token in cookie which will be used by other applications.  Can you post code related to Identityserver configuration in startup class and handling the token in the clients (webapi and web application).

Comment: I uploaded a complete solution on: [https://github.com/josuemb/authentication-example](https://github.com/josuemb/authentication-example)

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem yet?